# What audio formats does QAudioDecoder support?

Tags: c++, qt

In the documentation [QAudioDecoder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodecoder.html) is mentioned to throw a `FormatError` when 'The format of a media resource isn't supported.'

My question is what formats **does** `QAudioDecoder` support and could more formats be supported by users installing software such as LAME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function for that:

```
  QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
  qDebug() << info.supportedCodecs();
```

IIRC it should support MP3 if you have LAME installed, FLAC if you have FLAC installed and so on in that fashion. By default it is only guaranteed to support pcm wav.